# Least amount of hassle when enabling inline javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, inline

So I'm currently trying to run a react/react-redux/bootstrap web application template using react-app-rewired. To be specific, I run `npm start`, which runs `react-app-rewired start` via the predefined start script in my `package.json` file. The only error that's getting thrown is that in one of the .less files, there is some inline javascript. I'm ok with just allowing that to get through, because I'm sure there's also inline javascript in some of these other files, and having to fix every file this applies to would be a pain. I did some research, and the main way I see people accomplish this is by setting up gulp or webpack to pass enableJavascript as an option. Is there a way to enable inline javascript from the command line, and not take all that time setting up webpack or gulp on a premade program?

If there isn't, what is the way to accomplish this that comes with the least amount of headaches?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What do you mean by `there is some inline javascript` in your less files? Could you include the code in the question?

Comment: I'm gonna be honest, this template was one that had to be bought, so I'm not sure if that's ok for me to do. I'll see if I can describe this error in detail. The error points out a line of code that looks like this `.bezierEasingMixin()`. The .less file itself spends the whole file creating this function, then calling it with the before mentioned code at the end.

Comment: If the template is using `react-app-rewired` you are already using Webpack under the hood. Did you buy a template, and the first thing that happened was that you got this error? Or have you included things of your own?

Comment: This was buy the template, download, open in visual studio, install npm, run npm start out of the box. Scripts for npm were already included

Comment: "install npm", or run `npm install`? You might just have to install the dependencies with `npm install`

Comment: I ran npm install initially